# Simple script for google spreadsheet needed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm very new to the googledocs and scripts and could really do with a helping hand.

I need a script that would:

- duplicate the 1st sheet (1st in order)
- place the duplicate in the first positions
- rename the duplicate to current date
- delete all the rows below the first one in the duplicate file (e.g. 2nd to 300th row)

I had an attempt, but it does only part of the work... and doesn't seem to work properly. This is what I have got:

```
function myFunction() { 
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().duplicateActiveSheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().renameActiveSheet("New Sheet");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; 
  // Rows start at "1" - this will delete the first two rows 
  sheet.deleteRows(2, 100); 
}
```

Thank you very much reading!

Comment: It's not all that likely you'll find someone to just write a script for you.  However, if you try and have specific questions, please post them.  On that note, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, yes. I had an attempt, but it does only part of the work... and doesn't seem to work properly.
This is what I have got: 

function myFunction() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().duplicateActiveSheet();
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().renameActiveSheet("New Sheet");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
 // Rows start at "1" - this will delete the first two rows
 sheet.deleteRows(2, 100);
}

Comment: Its generally a good idea on stack, to put the code you've tried in your post, as opposed to comments.  Add your code to your post.  Also, add why the code doesn't work properly or as you expect.  It looks like a good start, but its hard to read in the comments section.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is keeping track of what spreadsheet is "active" - since you want to duplicate the first sheet, you need to make sure the first sheet is "active". (You can't just assume that it is.)

Once you've duplicated the first sheet, the new sheet will be "active". That's useful, since some of the operations you want to do will operate only on the "active" sheet.

```
function myFunction() { 
  // Make the first sheet active in the active workbook
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]);

  // duplicate the 1st sheet (1st in order)
  var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().duplicateActiveSheet();

  // place the duplicate in the first positions
  ss.moveActiveSheet(1);

  // rename the duplicate to current date
  newSheet.setName((new Date()).toDateString());

  // delete all the rows below the first one in the duplicate file (e.g. 2nd to 300th row)
  var lastRow =  newSheet.getLastRow();
  newSheet.deleteRows(2, lastRow-1);
}
```